# Can't make mat-paginator work, entire data is loaded

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, mat-table

i have a table and im trying to add pagination with mat-paginator and the instructions from Angular documentation but it keeps loading the entire table in the first page

I have tried

```
setTimeout(() => this.tableDataSource.paginator = this.paginator);
```

and

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tableDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Here is my component

```
[...]
displayedColumns: string[] = ['BookTitulo', 'BookAutor', 'BookGenero'];
  data: Book[];
  tableDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Book>(this.data);
  isLoadingResults = true;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getBooks()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.data = res;
        console.log(this.data);
        this.tableDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Book>(this.data);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
      });

  }
[...]
```

and here is my table

```
[...]
<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableDataSource" class="example-table"
           matSort matSortActive="BookTitulo" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="asc">


      <!-- Book Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="BookTitulo">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Titulo</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.BookTitulo}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Book Price Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="BookAutor">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Autor</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.BookAutor}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Book Price Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="BookGenero">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Genero</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.BookGenero}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [routerLink]="['/book-details/', row._id]"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 3, 5]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
[...]
```

I have tried what other post says but nothing works, please help and thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you create a demo code on https://stackblitz.com. I'll try to pick from there .

Answer (score 0):

You usually cannot add your `paginator` `ngAfterViewInit`, because the `mat-table` already called the `connect()` method. Try in the `ngOnInit` if your paginator is not dynamic (not affected by an `*ngIf`.
Greetings